# How to Decrement an Incremented counter as long as it stays zero or above and returns 0 instead of "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, increment, product-quantity

incrementing and decrementing works as expected but I need the number to display '0' instead of 'undefined' if it becomes zero or less.

Currently, When it becomes zero, it goes one step more and returns undefined.
I need it to stay zero when it gets to zero.

```js
let counter = 0;

const add = (function() {
  return function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
  }
})();
const sub = (function() {
  return function() {
    if (counter >= 1) {
      counter -= 1;
      return counter;
    }
  }

})();

function addFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}

function subFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sub();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttons {
  background: crimson;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="subFunction()">-</button>
    <p id="demo">0</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Move `return counter` out of the `if` block. You're not returning anything when the counter doesn't change.

Comment: Small question: is there a particular reason you've made the code as complicated as it is?

Comment: Thank you Barmer ! That's correct. @Barmer

Comment: @Andy I'm learning as I go..Probably because I'm not familiar with other methods out there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything when your condition fails. Just return your counter behind your if, so it will always return something.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

*{margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

.buttons{ background: crimson; margin:10px; width: 130px; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 4px; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border-radius: 5px;}

button{width: 45px; height: 20px; margin: 5px;}

p{margin: 5px;}


</style>

<body>

<div class="buttons">
<button type="button" onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="subFunction()">-</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
</div>

<!--Script-->
<script>
let counter = 0;

const add = (function () {
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter;}
})();
const sub = (function () {
  return function () {
  if(counter >= 1) {counter -= 1; return counter;}
  return counter
  }


 
})();

function addFunction(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
function subFunction(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sub();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could clean the code a bit by using the function directly without returning a function without cause.

```js
let counter = 0;

const
    add = () => ++counter,
    sub = () => counter = Math.max(0, --counter),
    addFunction = () => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(),
    subFunction = () => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sub();
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="subFunction()">-</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to `return 0` in your `sub()` function as the fallback condition (else condition)

```
const sub = (function() {
  return function() {
    if (counter >= 1) {
      counter -= 1;
      return counter;
    }
    return 0
  }

})();
```

---

***Working code below***

```js
let counter = 0;

const add = (function() {
  return function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
  }
})();
const sub = (function() {
  return function() {
    if (counter >= 1) {
      counter -= 1;
      return counter;
    }
    return 0
  }

})();

function addFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}

function subFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sub();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttons {
  background: crimson;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="subFunction()">-</button>
    <p id="demo">0</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```